# Declaring controls in multi form/usercontroll game

Tags: c#

In my game I have 2+ forms and 4+ usercontrols.
Where should I declare, lets say a textbox that I use in form2, but I need to modify it in form1.

Should I make them public in their own form/usercontrol or should I make a static class with all the controls?

(Edited to clarify my question)
I want to know the most used and flexible way.

Comment: From the FAQ: "Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?" I don't think so.

Comment: This belongs at stackoverflow.

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig: but but... a game programmer would optimize for speed, then everything is public members (save function calls), no? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would make the actual TextBox private in its Form, then expose functionality (like get/set text) using either methods or properties, depending on 'obviousness' factor, ie:

```
public string Text1
{
    get { return myTextBox1.Text; }
    set { myTextBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

or...

```
public void SetTextFromVars(int var1, DateTime var2)
{
    myTextBox1.Text = String.Format("Hey, I have got {0} objects since {1}", var1, var2);
}
```